How can I dynamically create my Linq statement
I've been searchng for an example to create my linq statement dynamically, but I've not managed to find an answer.
IQueryable<Booking> booking;

I then do an intial Lambda returning a number of bookings into my IQueryable.
on each booking we have some boolean columns in my case 4. Each of these are an approval reason and these are nullable so each could be 'null', 1 or 0.
If I was only interested in one of my 4 reasons because the user has only specified filtering by filter1, I might do:
booking = booking.Where(b => b.filter1 == 1)

and that would work fine. I want to be able to extend this to be:
booking = booking.Where(b => b.filter1 == 1 || b.filter2 == 1....and so on
I only want to include the filter on the where clause if the filter has been selected by the user.
It has been suggested, that my question has already been answered. The author suggesting this is directing me toward using 'PredicateBuilder'.
This looks like a good tool, however, everything I find on this shows that initiating it only uses 1 type e.g.
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Class1>();

However, my started for 10 needs to have the following converted to using a PredicateBuilder, and I'm not sure it can cope.
My original Linq starts:
    IQueryable<Booking> booking;

    booking = (from b in _context.Bookings.Include(v => v.Vendor).Include(v => v.PurchaseOrder).ThenInclude(v => v.PurchaseOrderDestinations).Include(l => l.LineLevelBookings).Include(d => d.BookingDangerousGoods) select b);


First step you have to extract Where(....) to Func Where(MyFunc)

@MustafaMutasim That would prevent the query provider from applying the filter, forcing it to query the entire data set and filter everything client side.

@Servy, yes that's a long story, Memory\Performance\traffic... wise. In my case, I load all data in the client side in a readonly Enumerable as a cache storage to reduce calling the database, and I have an event to request new data if there is changes.

@MustafaMutasim That forces the query to run the condition against every single item, instead of being able to leverage indexes to find the items in question directly.  But regardless, that you've decided to do whatever you've decided to do in your own application is your choice, but this question is about writing queries against an IQueryable, not an IEnumerable.

@Servy, Your advice is greatly appreciated, Thanks!
